# Is using desktop 2FA clients like Authy Desktop a good practice?

Tags: multi-factor, integrity, smartphone

Basically 2FA relies on the idea that instead of just something you know, using a service also requires something you own.

I am quite confident, especially when used on iOS (which has a better system level app segregation), that this gives a pretty good security. Though I am not sure about adding a desktop 2FA utility.

In my understanding, an attacker would need to intercept my password (likely through a keylogger on my desktop machine were I log most) and an access to my phone, or to the key stored on my phone. But I can likely picture that someone able to setup a keylogger could steal enough information to reuse any 2FA system available on my desktop computer.

Writing this I am understanding that this is based on the perception that:

**Computer integrity < Phone integrity < iOS integrity**

Computer are more likely to be corrupted through the pile of junk I am installing on it and their more important "openness" to system changes.

Smartphones have a more restrictive ecosystem and a shorter livespan, thus a lighter probability to be infected.

iOS, is comparatively the most closed ecosystem where unlike on Android most access are not opened in API and the app checking is more thorough.

Comment: More importantly, a piece of malware on your computer can't access your phone directly. It's two different devices, with different vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You made an assumption that affects your outcome, and you cannot forget that you are making this assumption: that one "likely" gets your password via the desktop computer (i.e. keylogger). If that is your threat analysis, that's perfectly fine, just don't forget that you have made this differentiation.

Since your threat analysis is desktop-based, then yes, your conclusion is correct that adding a security function to the already-assumed-to-be-compromised desktop does not add a layer of security. If one can get your password, then one can get your 2FA code.

But, a desktop 2FA option is not useless if we change our assumptions. If we assume that one is more likely to get our passwords from the services we use (instead of our desktops), or even that one can get passwords from our mobile devices, then the desktop security measure legitimately adds a useful security function.

The ultimate question becomes: what ***is*** the most likely vector of password compromise? And that question changes constantly. And that's why being mindful of our threat assessments and reviewing them from time to time is very important.

So, the desktop 2FA option is a valid one, depending on your threat analysis.

Comment: what I understand from your answer, and please correct me if I'm wrong, is that 2FA is something companies do to cover their basses. In this way, 2FA does increase protection when it comes to companies messing up, but it does little to nothing to increase protection when it comes to customers messing up. I suppose I just wrongly assumed that the 2 factors of authenticating are the password and the pin, but actually is the company and the client. In the sense that the (1fa) company and the (2fa) client needs to mess up for a breach of security. Or just the client twice, but who keeps count...

Comment: No, 2FA is an extremely effective control against stolen passwords. If the device that generates the 2FA code is compromised, it is possible that the protection is weakened. But you can't talk about security or controls in such stark, absolutist terms. Passwords and 2FA are both shared secrets. The 2FA code has better protections than a memorised password.

Comment: "against stolen passwords", but it really makes a huge difference where those passwords are stolen from the company, or from the user. How does the 2FA compromised device only reduces security, and it doesn't break it, when almost always, which means always in practical terms, a 2FA device also saves the first factor? I see how 2FA is an extremely effective control against stolen passwords from the company, but I don't understand what security 2FA brings against stolen passwords from the user, aka the 2FA device.

Comment: You are making broad assumptions about how the passwords were stolen and the context. On a ***phone*** apps are separated from each other, so the compromise of a browser does not mean the compromise of the 2FA app. But the context here is the ***desktop***. So, just like the OP, you need to keep your assumptions and risk context in mind.

Comment: My assumption is that people prefer to not use 2 devices for authentication, and this practice is extremely widely observed. Moreover, I don't know of any company which attempts to hard or even soft enforce a 2device policy. Removing this assumption moves the discussion beyond the reality and into the realm of security theory. Moreover, I understood your point that 2FA increases security on the company side, but if your point is that 2FA also increases the security on the client side,for those clients that use 2 separate devices, then great for those 1%, but it doesn't do anything for the rest

Comment: I challenge your claim that people do not use their phones for 2FA when logging into services using their laptops/desktops. Every single company I have worked with (well over 40 companies in the past 3 years) uses phones for 2FA No company needs a 2 device policy for this.  So, you might need to refine your understanding of your assumptions.

Comment: fair enough. I am now just curious, did those companies have their own 2FA system, or did they allow the use of authenticator apps, such as the microsoft, google, or authy? If it is the former, then in a way, they would have quite a hard policy that at least the second factor has to happen on a mobile device, now the only thing left to do is block access to any company service from mobile devices (did they?). If it's the latter, how do you know that people were not using desktop authenticators for desktop access and mobile authenticators for mobile access?

Comment: If your point is that 2FA improves the security on the client side because users are generally speaking responsible and never use the same device for the first and second factor authentication on a service, then your point is clear to me. I personally believe that generally speaking users do not have the necessary information to be that responsible, and this is also what I observe in practice around me, but I can also understand that users on your side of the world may be better educated, therefore more responsible when it comes to separating the 2 factors of authentication.

Comment: My point is that 2FA codes generated on the ***desktop*** can create problems.